# Issue related to HTML body in Predefined Field Value Edit of email

Tags: formula

I am new to salesforce as a beginner, I am trying add some paragraph in HTML body as it is taking text but I am getting this kind of error .I am not going to any coding part just entering text . Please help me on this issue.

Thanks
[image]

Answer (score 0):

A formula isn't just "plain text". It's something like halfway between "text" and "writing code".

That is to say, you need to follow some specific rules when creating a formula,
but there are fewer rules (and fewer possibilities) than if you were writing code.

In your specific case:

- You need to concatenate your strings (using the `&` or `+` operators)
- Adding line breaks (newlines) means you need to use the `BR()` function
- When referencing data on parent objects, custom relationship fields need to have `__r` instead of `__c` (e.g. `MyAccount__r.Manager__r.Name`), and you cannot pull in data from child records (only parents, grandparents, etc... up to 5 levels high)

Trailhead is generally the place to go to to start learning about parts of Salesforce. [This selection of modules, projects, and trails on writing formulas](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/search/learning?keywords=formulas) should get you started.

Other than that, I'd say that what you're looking for here is not a formula, but rather an [Email template](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.email_templates_lightning_parent.htm&type=5)